# MongoDB Bulk Update is slow

Tags: javascript, mongodb, bulkinsert, node-mongodb-native

I'm running Mongo 2.6.3  I'm updating about 900 records, and sometimes up to 5000 records.  I had this in a loop before, and for 900 records the upserts took about 1 minute to complete.

Right now, I'm using the initializeUnorderedBulkOp API and it's taking about 40 seconds for 900 records.  Why is it so slow?

I basically have

```
var batch = collection.initializeUnorderedBulkOp({useLegacyOps: true});
// for loop
batch.find(query).upsert().updateOne({my object});
batch.execute({w:0},function(err, result) {
```

This is using the node driver.  Screenshot of my network panel for these calls http://cl.ly/image/0L2a0o0w1I1b

When the data is smaller, it takes less time, so it's definitely a number of records problem. Lastly, my objects are not huge, they are maybe 9 keys or so, no big data.

Any ideas on how to get this time down?

Comment: Can `query` use an index?  If not, make sure it can.

Comment: Can we have more information? What is the query? Is it indexed? What are the updates? What indexes exist on the collection?

Comment: Ugh, indexing is the answer. You should leave that so I can mark it. I'm dumb for not realizing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your comment, your `find` query is not using an index which will prompt a full collection scan.

Add an index to your collection that can be used by `find(query)`; use [`explain()`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.explain/) to confirm it's being used.